# Security folder missing from the registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Security

Tags: security, microsoft-outlook, windows-registry, office365

I need to add a `DWORD` value in

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Security
```

but the Security folder is missing in the registry. I have Office365 (version 1903, build 11425.20202)

How can I add this missing DWORD value?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> Folders are called Keys in the windows registry, you can create a new key manually 
>   - Moab
>
> right click Outlook and select New > Key. After that right click Security key and select New > DWORD 
>   - Perry